# Using p5.js to try and make a repeating pattern that looks like the flower of life, bit stuck

Tags: javascript, for-loop, geometry, p5.js, nested-for-loop

I'm doing an art project on sacred geometry and want to create my own flower of life pattern on p5.js. After a lot of trial and error I've managed to get 6 circles intersecting evenly while rotating around 1 inner circle. The problems come when I try to move the centre of the central circle, as all the other circles are algebraically related to that circle, it changes how much the circles overlap, which I don't want.

Also the for loop isn't working and crashes the code every time I load it!

Here is my code:

```js
let x = 100;
let y = 115;
let r = 40;
//x and y being the origin of the middle circle

let a = 0;
let b = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

  // Circle 1 parameters
  x1 = (4 / 5) * x;
  y1 = (16 / 23) * y;

  // Circle 2 parameters
  x2 = (6 / 5) * x;
  y2 = (16 / 23) * y;

  //3 MIDDLE
  x3 = x;
  y3 = y;

  // circle 4 mid left
  x4 = x - r;
  y4 = y;

  // circle 5 mid right
  x5 = x + r;
  y5 = y;

  // Circle 6 parameters
  x6 = (6 / 5) * x;
  y6 = (30 / 23) * y;

  // circle 7 
  x7 = (4 / 5) * x;
  y7 = (30 / 23) * y;

}

function draw() {

  background(0);
  noFill(0, 0, 0, 0);
  stroke(260);

  //Draw circles
  for (var a = -80; a < 800; c0 = c + 40) {
    ellipse(x1 + a, y1 + b, r * 2, r * 2);
    ellipse(x2 + a, y2 + b, r * 2, r * 2);
    ellipse(x3 + a, y3 + b, r * 2, r * 2);
    ellipse(x4 + a, y4 + b, r * 2, r * 2);
    ellipse(x5 + a, y5 + b, r * 2, r * 2);
    ellipse(x6 + a, y6 + b, r * 2, r * 2);
    ellipse(x7 + a, y7 + b, r * 2, r * 2);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

I pretty new to coding so if I've done something stupid please let me know!! I was going to nest another for loop inside the first with the variable being "b" but as the first one isn't working I didn't get that far...

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I want to be able to create different patterns from repeating the initial 7-intersecting circle shape!